# ClassNotFoundException with class declared in manifest

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

Okay so i just started getting this error.

```
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.fttech.MenuActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.app-1.apk]
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
```

I have it declared in my manifest!

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Anyone know what this comes from?

EDIT:

Also i noticed it saying..

```
01-03 15:31:51.610: E/AndroidRuntime(14203): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.fttech.MenuActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.app-1.apk]
```

Where it should be  app_1.apk not apk-1.apk

Anyone have this problem?

Comment: What makes it random? Does it occur once in a while or always? *(it's not random just because you don't see it's underlying cause yet)* Also, just to be safe that nothing relevant is missing: Can you post the complete manifest and the full stacktrace? Thanks

Comment: You may want to check out my edit first. I think the issue persists there, because when i check my workspace folder outside of eclipse, the apk is name app_1.apk inside the stacktrace its trying to load app-1.apk for some reason.

Comment: It seems your MenuActivity class is in different package than the one defined in AndroidManifest.xml. I would suggest another thing, complete uninstall of app and reinstall.

Comment: That's what I wanted to see without guessing around. The packages probably don't match. Hence the full trace/manifest. The APK name is ok, they get renamed internally. If you have a rooted device, check out `/data/app` via the adb shell, all APKs get that suffix.

Comment: But it was random..I restarted my machine without closing out eclipse properly and then wala this happens. Any idea's on how to fix it

Comment: @thinksteep I tried that to no avail. As you see for some reason its pointing to the wrong .apk file.

Comment: I believe something happened and the entire project was corrupted. I created another project and moved everything over, and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the complete path to the Activity (With the package), clean the project and refresh the workspace.

Maybe you changed the launch activity or you changes the name and some garbage stayed.

Comment: Thanks but i tried this already. I think am just going to create another project and transfer everything.